# How best to design a REST API with multiple filters?

Tags: mysql, api, rest

As a personal programming project, I am working on scraping my University's course catalog and providing the data as a REST API. I have successfully scraped all the data and stored it in a database, and am now working on the API.

The courses can be filtered on the basis  of many criteria: instructor, college, credits, time, day etc.

What is the best way to provide an API in this situation?

**Option 1**

Provide numerous URLs such as

```
example.com/api/byinstructor/<instructorcode>
example.come/api/bycollege/<collegecode>
example.com/api/bycollegeandinstructor/<collegecode>/<instructorcode>
...and so on
```

I would need to have a URL for all permutations. This seems very cumbersome, both for me and the API consumers, and very un-DRY.

**Option 2**

Only provide APIs for the major options like:

```
example.com/api/byinstructor/<instructorcode>
example.come/api/bycollege/<collegecode>
```

And if the consumer wants `bycollegeandinstructor`, he does the filtering on his end.

**Option 3**

The user passes a JSON string to me, and I use that to get the filtering criteria

```
example.com/api/getcourses/<jsonstring>

jsonstring = 
{ 
  instructor:<instructorcode>,
  college:<collegecode>,
  ...and so on
}
```

I suppose instead of the Json string, I could also require a POST array, but that seems un-inituitive for the consumer since he is GETing data.

Or is there another way of doing this I am not aware of? If it is the third option that is the best option, could you provide a short summary best to prepare a SQL query on the basis of a JSOn string that may have variable number of values?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To expand on the answer from J.F., it sounds like you have one resource, the set of courses, which would be at the URI:

```
/courses
```

Filtering that resource is usually accomplished using query parameters to filter that single resource, e.g:

```
/courses?college=123&instructor=321
```

By doing this, you avoid the issue with all possible permutations creating a proliferation of resources.

Fundamentally: There's one resource, which can be filtered as necessary.

Comment: Thanls. I wasn't thinking in terms of resources until I read yhour answer

Comment: Technically, those are still distinct resources. You don't really avoid permutation issues this way; in fact, you increase those issues slightly by allowing college=123&instructor=321 to return the same response as instructor=321&college=123. Because of this explosion, many caches will not cache a response that has query parameters unless you explicitly configure them to do so.

For that reason, I generally recommend option 2 if you can identify some common patterns in the requests people make.

Comment: @fumanchu That's interesting about caches ignoring responses to requests with query parameters, I was not aware of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
GET example.com/courses?college=<collegecode>&instructor=<instructorcode>
```

Comment: and the consumer is allowed to pass as many or as few GET parameters as they want?

Comment: @xbonez: yes. In the absence of a constraint you could use default values appropriate for your application e.g., personalize the filtering if the user is known.