# REST Webservices - GET but for multiple objects

Tags: rest

I have already gone through this
[How best to design a REST API with multiple filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806844/how-best-to-design-a-rest-api-with-multiple-filters)

This does help when you have say 3 or 4 filtering criteria and you can accomodate that in the query String.

However let's take this example
You want to get call details about 20 telephone numbers, between a certain startdate and enddate.
Now I do agree ideally one should be advised to make individual queries for each number and then on the client side collate all data.

However for certain Live systems that would mean 20 rounds of queries on the switches or cdr databases. That is 20 request-response cycles plus the client having to collate and order them again based on time. While in the database level it would have been a simple single query that can return an ordered data and transformed back into a REST xml response that the client can embed on their system.

If we are to use GET the query string will get really confusing and has a limit as well.
Any suggestions to get around this issue.
Of course we can send a POST request with an xml having all numbers in it but that is against REST Get principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be missing is an important concept of REST, [caching](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#fig_5_7). This can be done, as an example, in the browser, for a single client. Or it can be done as a [shared cache](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~voelker/pubs/org-sharing-usits99.pdf) between all the clients and the live production system (whatever it may be). Thus reducing queries against a live production system, or in your example, actual switches.

You should really take some time to read [Fieldings thesis](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm), and understand that REST is an ***architectural style***.

Comment: Thanks. I assume by shared cache you mean a temp data store that the client queries and which gets periodically updated by the main Live servers/switches so that the server only outputs data to the intermediate cache and is never queried. While the cache can be queried as much possible. But are you saying to send queries for one number at a time and send 20 requests for 20 numbers but the queries run against the temp data store?

Comment: @Soumya As an example, what you wrote. Or if client A pulls 20 queries and, by agreement, those are valid for 48h. Those 20 queries are shared on the middleware cache for all clients to use. How this solution is to be implemented is up to you - what I'm saying is, this is a solution that is compliant by those contraints set by REST.

Comment: Thanks. I also went through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127507/handling-multiple-parameters-in-a-uri-restfully-in-java .                                   However in my case building up a intermediate cache isn't really an option and we already have a system that we are querying. Only difference is before it used to a POST request with an XML for any kind of request, including fetch ones. So we didn't have any trouble. However now we are trying to migrate to REST based services and having this issue where it conflicts with REST GET principles.

Answer (score 3):

In case of GET use OData queries. For example when your start and end dates represented as numbers (unix time) URI could look like:

GET http://operatorcalls.com/Calls/Details?$filter=Date le 1342699200 and Date gt 1342526400

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here [Handling multiple parameters in a URI (RESTfully) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127507/handling-multiple-parameters-in-a-uri-restfully-in-java)
but not quite happy with it.
So in effect we will end up using /cdr?numbers=number1,number2,number3 ...
However not too pleased with it as there is a limit to Query String in the url and also doesn't really seem to be an elegant solution. Anyone found any solution to this in their own implementation?
Basically not using POST for this kind of Fetch requests and also not using cumbresome and lengthy Query Strings.
We are using Jersey but also open to using CXF or Spring REST